# calculate and add a value of Form Input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i m new to javascript, just want to create simple addition in my page, below is my code,
if INPUT1 is 100 then output should be 250 but below is not working(showing output as 100150).

```
<form name="TEST"> 
<input type="number" name="INPUT1" id="input" onchange="calculate();"/>
<input type="hidden" name="INPUT2" id="input" value="150" />
<input type="number" name="OUTPUT" id="output">
</form>   

<script type="text/javascript">  
function calculate()  {  
var CALC1 = document.TEST.INPUT1.value;     
var CALC2 = document.TEST.INPUT2.value;    
var CALC3 = CALC1 + CALC2;    
document.TEST.OUTPUT.value = CALC3;    
}
```

Comment: the type number for input specifys the type of textbox

Comment: @Sney19—the value of an input is always a string, regardless of its (HTML) type.

Comment: yes i was trying to make the same point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is taking calc1 and calc2 as a string 
try using a parseInt(Calc1)+parseInt(Calc2)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with java but anyway. Values are string, so you can't calculate them like that. You need to parse values to integer and then calculate.

`var CALC1 = parseInt(document.TEST.INPUT1.value);`